# After successful installation of cjklib and CEDICT, when I use it, it throw errors, why?

Tags: python, cjk

This is my first post here.

I have been reading posts here since I started learning python and it has been nothing but a great help to my learning process. So, just want to say A BIG THANK YOU to you all before my question!

**Question:**

I installed the cjklib package successfully. Then, I installed the CEDICT dictionary successfully as well. But when I try to use CEDICT, it always throws errors like this:

```
>>> d = CEDICT()
......
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 335, in do_execute
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) unknown database "cedict_0" 'PRAGMA "cedict_0".table_info("CEDICT")' ()
>>>
```

**To reproduce the problem:**

*Install the cjklib package:*

Download the cjklib-0.3.tar.gz, extract it and update the files in directory Cjklib-0.3/cjklib/build/*.py (specifically, builder.py and **init**.py):

Update "from sqlalchemy.exceptions" to "from sqlalchemy.exc"

```
$cd djklib-0.3/cjklib/build/
$sudo python setup.py install
$sudo installcjkdict CEDICT
$python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:39:59) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from cjklib.dictionary import CEDICT
>>> d = CEDICT()
```

The error occurs, in details, as below:

```
>>> d = CEDICT()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cjklib/dictionary/__init__.py", line 605, in __init__
    super(CEDICT, self).__init__(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cjklib/dictionary/__init__.py", line 532, in __init__
    super(EDICTStyleEnhancedReadingDictionary, self).__init__(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cjklib/dictionary/__init__.py", line 269, in __init__
    if not self.available(self.db):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cjklib/dictionary/__init__.py", line 276, in available
    and dbConnectInst.hasTable(cls.DICTIONARY_TABLE))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cjklib/dbconnector.py", line 444, in hasTable
    schema = self._findTable(tableName)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cjklib/dbconnector.py", line 429, in _findTable
    if hasTable(tableName, schema=schema):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2525, in has_table
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2412, in run_callable
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1959, in run_callable
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base.py", line 567, in has_table
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1450, in execute
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1627, in _execute_text
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1697, in _execute_context
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1690, in _execute_context
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 335, in do_execute
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) unknown database "cedict_0" 'PRAGMA "cedict_0".table_info("CEDICT")' ()
>>>
```

**Tryouts:**
I tried some solutions myself, like:

As the error indicated, it can't find the table in the sqlite database file, so I edited the cjklib.conf file by adding following the line to tell it that the table is right here:

```
url = sqlite:////usr/local/share/cjklib/cedict.db
```

Then, it found the table CEDICT and stopped throwing the errors. But unfortunately, it started throwing another kind of error when I ran the code below:

```
>>> from cjklib import characterlookup
>>> cjk = characterlookup.CharacterLookup('T')
```

Error:

```
>>> cjk = characterlookup.CharacterLookup('T')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cjklib/characterlookup.py", line 118, in __init__
    self.hasComponentLookup = self.db.hasTable('ComponentLookup')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cjklib/dbconnector.py", line 444, in hasTable
    schema = self._findTable(tableName)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cjklib/dbconnector.py", line 429, in _findTable
    if hasTable(tableName, schema=schema):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2525, in has_table
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2412, in run_callable
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1959, in run_callable
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base.py", line 567, in has_table
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1450, in execute
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1627, in _execute_text
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1697, in _execute_context
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1690, in _execute_context
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 335, in do_execute
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) unknown database "cjklib_0" 'PRAGMA "cjklib_0".table_info("ComponentLookup")' ()
```

If i delete the line I added, it will work as expected again.

**Solutions:**

How can I make it read both cedict.db and cjklib.db at the same time? I am guessing, only then, it might work for both cases without throwing any errors.

Did anyone encounter a similar situation? And how did you solve it? Or, do you have anything else to try out in mind? Just shed some lights please!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Your method to make CEDICT work is **not complete**.  Although "d = CEDICT()" doesn't raise any error, you will meet an error when you a dictionary function, such as "d.getFor(u'朋友')". You should add an item in the config file:

```
attach = sqlite:////usr/local/share/cjklib/cjklib.db
```

But, this method still gives a "characterlookup" error (as you mentioned).

(2) Real solution: create "dbconnection" explicitly for the dictionary.

```
>>> from cjklib.dictionary import CEDICT
>>> from cjklib.dbconnector import getDBConnector
>>> db = getDBConnector({'sqlalchemy.url': 'sqlite://', 'attach': ['cjklib']})
>>> d=CEDICT(dbConnectInst=db)
>>> it=d.getFor(u'朋友')
```

**EDIT:**

Keep cjklib.conf with default configuration.

Comment: Just did! i am new here, so wasn`t aware of how to award people yet!

Answer (score 0):

This error can also happen in a multi-threaded environment when you have initialized the CEDICT() object globally in python, but then you try to use the same object in a newly created thread.

The solution is to create the object inside the thread that you intend to do the dictionary lookups.